# I need to fix a recess light in my kitchen?

Tags: recessed-lighting

I have recessed lighting in my entire house. It has vaulted ceilings and there is not attic access. One fixture keeps going through lamps and now just flickers on and off. Well, it did until my nephew removed the screw completely from the housing to see if he could take out the can.

What do I do now? We have taken off the trim and removed the baffle, but he dropped the screw that connected to a wing nut inside the can behind the light. I don't how to fix it or if I have to cut a hole in the ceiling to remove the housing? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the breaker to this circuit.
Near the bottom of the can light there are three screws. Remove them and the entire inner tin-can should pull down out of the ceiling. You can now rescue that screw and deal with whatever the problem is. This also provides you access to the junction box that is part of the lamp; where its connections are that you need to inspect.

A can light that seems to turn itself on and off either has too high of wattage bulb in it, causing the over-temp sensor to trip. Or the over temp switch has failed and needs to be replaced.

I am at a loss as to why one would burn out bulbs faster than others, unless it is somehow subject to more vibration. I'd check it against the others with a meter to make sure everything was kosher.

Comment: The lamp holder inside of the can might be defective which is causing the bulb to arc, blink, and eventually fail.